# custom dialog crashes the application when opened second time

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I am using a custom dialog with list view. Whenever I open this dialog for second time, it crashes my entire application.

I get a nullpointer exception at

java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 05:02:47.222: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.forceUniformWidth(LinearLayout.java:930)

I am following view holder pattern to populate listveiw.
When I open the dialog for second time I have noticed that contentView is not null. Is that normal. I am dismissing the dialog once the user selects the option.

can someone please suggest. Thanks in adavance

Comment: any snippet of code and logcat?

Comment: Post your code and logcat.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that second time your Listview become null.So,there is no data to set in Listview and it give null pointer exception.

Check that your data always available or not..........

Hope this post useful to you........

Comment: listview has the data on second time as well.